# How can i remove an event of a button or another control?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

I have created the button_click event of my button and also this

```
private void btnDergo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

}
```

by accident.. Now that i have that code on my Form, how do i remove it?
I've tried by just deleting the it as a simple text, but it doesn't work.. Is there any way i can remove that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove it in the property/event window, then it should be removed everywhere. You can also search for the eventhandler in the ...design.cs file and delete it there.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an event, you should delete it from the `Form.Designer.cs`.

**1.** First, go to the visual studio solution explorer and click here

[image]

**2.** Click here to open the `Form.Designer.cs`

[image]

**3.** Expand `Windows Form Designer generated code` by clicking here

[image]

**4.** Delete the line that adds the event handler

[image]